# Pandas - Get the corresponding value from dictionary while comparing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a **dictionary** (not a dataframe) like this,

```
Emp ID  dictvalue
1        True
2        False
```

And I have a dataframe like this,

```
  Emp ID    ColA       ColB
     1          A         B
     2          A         A
```

I am doing a compare between ColA and ColB

```
temp_result_df[res_col_name] = (temp_result_df[primaryreportreqcolname] == temp_result_df[RequiredSecondaryReport_Col_Name])
```

I am looking for an or logic in the code, that will have the dictvalue (Boolean true or false) from the dictionary by mapping with the empid.
It will be a lot easier for me, if it is on the same line of code for my convenient maintenance.

Something like,

```
temp_result_df[res_col_name] = (temp_result_df[primaryreportreqcolname] == temp_result_df[RequiredSecondaryReport_Col_Name]) | ??...dictvalue......??
```

I don't want to add dict as a new column to this temp_result_df at this point.
Converting the dictionary to a dataframe and doing a join will be an easy solution. But, I will have to drop that column again and the next operations will become messier as this is present in multiple places.

The expected result,

```
  Emp ID    ColA       ColB   result
     1          A         B    True
     2          A         A    True
```

The Emp ID 1 returns a False while comparing ColA and ColB but on OR logic with the dictvalue coming from the dataframe, it becomes a True.

Comment: Well. Joining will be the easiest solution. But there are operations performed in the data frame and that would get affected. Unless I drop the column again.

Comment: Can you just clarify what your expected outcome is. Why do both rows have 'true' in the result column?

Comment: Yes, the Emp Id 1 gives the result of False while comparing ColA and ColB. But it becomes a True because there is an OR logic with the dictvalue of the dictionary.

Comment: @Hari_Sheldon done now. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, 1 more, the dictionary won't contain all the ID's that are in the dataframe?

Comment: No, the dictionary will contain all the ID's that are in the df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) chained with bitwise `OR`:

```
d = {1:True, 2:False}

df['result'] = (df['ColA'] == df['ColB']) | df['Emp ID'].map(d)
print (df)
   Emp ID ColA ColB  result
0       1    A    B    True
1       2    A    A    True
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['ColA'] == df['ColB'])
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool

print (df['Emp ID'].map(d))
0     True
1    False
Name: Emp ID, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying with apply concept. Forgot the map. Thanks again.